# matplotlib subplot of 1:2:1

Tags: matplotlib, layout, subplot

I'm trying to plot an A4 PDF with the following layout:

1. 1 chart spanning 2 columns
2. 2 charts, each spanning 1 column
3. 1 chart spanning 2 columns

I have the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.27,11.69))
ax = fig.add_subplot(311)
ax = fig.add_subplot(323)
ax = fig.add_subplot(324)
ax = fig.add_subplot(315)
```

but i'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 3, not 5
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(311)
ax = fig.add_subplot(323)
ax = fig.add_subplot(324)
ax = fig.add_subplot(313)
```

[image]

However, for this kind of thing, you will gain in readability if you use `GridSpec` https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html The following code yields the exact same output, but is (at least to me) easier to understand

```
fig = plt.figure()
gs = fig.add_gridspec(3, 2)
fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :])
fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1])
fig.add_subplot(gs[2, :])
```

Comment: why is the last one ending in 3? i.e. 313

Comment: because for the bottom axes you want to lay out a 3 row x 1 col grid, and on this grid the bottom axes are the 3rd axes, so `3,1,3` or `313`